# Spin$^c$ structures induced by an almost complex structure

Tags: complex-geometry, spin-geometry

Let $M$ be a closed spin$^c$ $4$-manifold with determinant line bundle $L$.

If $c_1^2(L)=2\chi(M)+3\tau(M)$, where $\chi$ and $\tau$ denote the Euler characteristic and signature of $M$ respectively, can we prove that the spin$^c$ structure is induced by some almost complex structure $J$ on $M$?

Comment: Is $M$ a 4-manifold, perhaps?

Comment: @MarcoGolla Yes.

Answer (score 6):

Briefly, let $W^+$ denote the positive spin bundle of the given $Spin_c$- structure so that $det(W^+)=L$. Then the condition

$
c_1^2(L)=2\tau(M)+3\sigma(M)
$

is equivalent, using a little characteristic class magic, to

$
c_2(W^+)=0.
$

The latter means (on a 4-manifold) that $W^+$ admits a non-vanishing section $\Phi$ which WLOG has unit length.  Clifford multiplication against this $\Phi$ induces a real isomorphism

$
\theta \in T^{*}M \mapsto c(\theta)\Phi \in W^-
$

so the cotangent bundle inherits being a complex vector bundle from the complex vector bundle $W^-$ and hence $M$ an almost complex structure.

Comment: ^An almost complex structure on a Riemannian manifold is (by definition) a complex structure on its (co)tangent bundle, so $W^-$ complex $\Rightarrow$ $T^*M$ complex $\Rightarrow$ $M$ almost-complex. (Your last sentence parses as: $TT^*M$ complex.) Probably just semantics, since by "complex structure on bundle" I mean fiberwise (i.e. complex bundle) not the bundle as a manifold.

Comment: Thanks Chris. Edited the answer a bit to take account of your comment.